# Asp.net membership web.config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to use the asp.net membership roles and profiles for a website I'm creating for my company.

I generated the tables through aspnet_regsql.exe

Now everything works fine, besides the fact that the tables generated through regsql.exe are been ignored and a whole new set of tables were added instead

1. dbo.Applications
2. dbo.Memberships
3. dbo.Profile
4. dbo.Roles
5. dbo.Users
6. dbo.UsersInRoles

My web.config looks like this:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I have tried to change the type to:

```
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
```

But then I get this error : *Configuration Error*
What am I doing wrong. Can I just keep using these new tables and delete the regsql_exe tables?